# Groupby distinct how can I do that?

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products>
     <product>
         <productId >1</productId>
          <textdate>11/11/2011</textdate>
          <price>200</price>
      </product>
  <product>
         <productId >6</productId>
          <textdate>11/11/2011</textdate>
          <price>100</price>
      </product>
  <product>
         <productId >1</productId>
          <textdate>16/11/2011</textdate>
          <price>290</price>
      </product>
</Products>
```

I've this xml and I want an xslt transformation that regroup product something like this :

{ product 1 :
      11/11/2011 - 200
      16/11/2011 - 290 }
   { product 6
      11/11/2011 - 100 }

I work with xslt 1.0 Asp .net C# XslCompiledTransformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Muenchian grouping as explained here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/index.xml. If you need help with writing the code then please state whether you want plain text output or HTML output in the format you posted.

Answer (score 1):

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="groupById" match="product" use="productId"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="product[
                        generate-id() =
                        generate-id( key( 'groupById', productId ) )
                        ]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:text>{ product </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(productId, ' : &#xa;')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key( 'groupById', productId )" mode="inner-content"/>
    <xsl:text> }&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product" mode="inner-content">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat( textdate, ' - ', price )"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your code sample, it will produce this result:

```
{ product 1 : 
11/11/2011 - 200
16/11/2011 - 290 }
{ product 6 : 
11/11/2011 - 100 }
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. Inner content could start with a new line (instead of inner most new line in `product` rule) and that way you avoid the position test.

Comment: How can I do the same but with the content of my xml in a variable?

Comment: @Christophe. It's better for you to post another question, providing full (but minimal as possible) XML/XSL and desired output samples.